# Exit status of sh command?

Tags: bash, shell, exit-status

Hi I am calling a shell script from inside another shell script and if that script call goes successful I have to proceed further and I am using sh command to call another script like :

```
sh payloadjob.sh
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo Success message 
else
    echo Failure message
fi
```

But  I am noticing that even script call go successful it gives 
Exit status as 1 however it should return 0 for success why it is happening and how do I come to know that script call via sh command is successful or not ?

Comment: I edited your question a bit to change the shell keywords to the correct case. `If` is different from `if`. I assume that wasn't the issue here, since you would have got a syntax error (or an error about `If` not found)

Comment: But FWIW, that looks like it should work in Bash or others with `[[ ]]`. Now the question just is, if `payloadjob.sh` even returns a sane return value.

Comment: Actually I have used same "if" and paylodjob.sh doesn't return anything

Comment: @unixbeginner Um, it _does_ return an exit status. The question is, why is it not returning the exit status that you _expect_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `payload.sh` script is not exiting with an explicit `exit 0` or `exit 1`, then the exit status of it will be that of the last command in the script.

If this last command does, for example, `rm something 2>/dev/null`, then the exit status will be non-zero if `something` can not be found or removed.

In the script that you have shown, you are correctly testing the `$?` variable.  You may also simplify the test to the equivalent

```
if sh payload.sh; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Comment: So this means whatever exit status I am getting is the exit status of last command within paylodjob.sh

Comment: @unixbeginner Correct.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda it was same issue that you pointed out

Comment: @unixbeginner you could also shorten that to `sh payload.sh && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"` if you like.